# In Django ,ajax to send the variable by Restful Api

Tags: ajax, django, rest

I am a rookie in the Restful,I want to send some variables to the viewset to response some filtering data by "GET"Now I have finished some parts ,I can get the all data,but I don't understand how to send variables  to a specific function in the viewset to response some filtering data , for example I crate a new function called "get_ajax_variable() " ,How could I to send variables to the 
 specific function ? 
appreciate in Advance!

This is my Serializer

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    Brand = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='brand_set.all', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = data_export_setting.Company_form_stand

    def create(self, validated_data): 
        validated_data['owner'] = self.context['request'].user
        return Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

This is my viewset

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

this is my ajax,the function of "showTable(json)" is a function to reload my company.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ab').click(function () {
            var filter_2 = $("#insert_value").val();//for City
            var filter_1 = $("#insert_value_1").val();// for Company type 
            var filter =  $('#filter').val();//for search 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {filter:filter, filter_1_value:filter_1,insert_value:insert_value},
                url: "https://horizon-retail-sam-leon-ghibli.c9users.io/restful_api/companyviewset/?format=json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType : 'application/json',
                success: function (json) {
                $('#ajax_search').empty();
                    showTable(json);
                    },
                error: function () {
                    alert("false");
                }
            });
        });



    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!I have solve this problem ,the following is my step
 the most important step is to overwrite function `get_queryset(self):` in the class of Viewset 
  in the template ,the ajax is as follows:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ab').click(function () {
            var filter_2 = $("#insert_value").val();//for City
            var filter_1 = $("#insert_value_1").val();// for Company type 
            var filter =  $('#filter').val();//for search 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                //data: {filter:filter, filter_1_value:filter_1,insert_value:insert_value},
            url:"You_own_url"+format=json&a="+filter+"&b="+filter_1+"&c="+filter_2,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType : 'application/json',
                success: function (json) {
                $('#ajax_search').empty();
                    showTable(json);
                    },
                error: function () {
                    alert("false");
                }
            });
        });
```

in the Setting of Django,you should set the `REST_FRAMEWORK`as

```
  'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
```

in the  Url of Django,you should set the url as follows:

```
router.register(r'companysearch',CompanyViewSet)
```

in the viewset,I did not pull all function of get_queryset, you should set as follows:

```
serializer_class = CompanySerializer
filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
def get_queryset(self):# how to define the null and None 
    filter_1 = self.request.query_params.get('a')#, None)  
    filter_company_type = self.request.query_params.get('b', None)# company_type
    filter_city_type = self.request.query_params.get('c', None)
   ....
```

then you can get the result correctly ,thanks anyone who helps

Answer (score 0):

since it's a GET, why dont you send them as url params ?

Comment: you mean in this way ? 
" url: "https://horizon-retail-sam-leon-ghibli.c9users.io/restful_api/companyviewset/?format=json"&a= filter_2&b=filter_1&c=filter"

Answer (score 0):

I should've replied as a comment but I don't have enough privilege to do it. So please bear with me.

I assume you are using Django Rest Framework(DRF) given the code and tags you put in the question.

Basically, this `url: "https://horizon-retail-sam-leon-ghibli.c9users.io/restful_api/companyviewset/?format=json",` allows you to send a request along with data to your REST API server, which is DRF in your setup. And `urls.py` in django get to know the value you sent and direct you to a certain view/viewset, for example, CompanyViewSet in your example.

And in terms of how the view/viewset works with a serializer, you can take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
and http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/. And this should suffice. I am not sure about how data got transferred from view/viewset to the serializer. It would be great if someone could explain. But in your serializer, your data should be in `validated_data`.

In that view/viewset, your data should be in `request.data` for POST and in GET, it usually in `query.params` but this really depends on how you construct the ajax call.

It is important to know the difference between POST and GET. You can simply google it.

HTH.